# Android 2.2.1 Nexus one : Voice recognition problem

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, android-2.2-froyo

HI Folks,

I have a strange problem for Voice recognition on Google Nexus one phone which
have Firmware:2.2.1.Voice recognition gives multiple interpretations
of the spoken word When I speak "Hello" to the voice recognition,
the results received is "hello, hotels, photos, fomdem, honda"
which is expected to come only "hello"
The same things works fine on Firmware 2.1 which give satisfactory result.

Whats has to be done to avoid this issue.Any Suggestions are helpful

Best Regards,
Vinayak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain the differnet behavior for different versions, but have you looked at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS ?

The intent accepts a Max Results parameter which tells the recognizer how many candidate strings to return to the client. Typically in speech recognition, the client may need to provide the user a disambiguation step (like "did you say "hello" or "hotel"?". If you only want the most likely candidate, set EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS to 1.